# Установка SSL сертификата на VPS

Tags: apache2, https, ssl, сертификат

Кто знает как установить сертификат от reg.ru на vps?

На почту пришло следующее

1. SSL-сертификат
2. Корневой сертификат
3. Промежуточный сертификат
4. Запрос на получение сертификата
5. Приватный ключ

Создал файл c сертификатом `/etc/ssl/site.ru.crt`

В файл `/etc/ssl/site.ru.intermediate.crt` вставил код корневого и промежуточного сертификата.

Код с запросом на получение сертификата `/etc/ssl/site.ru.csr`.

Приватный ключ вставил в файл `/etc/ssl/site.ru.private.key`.

В файле `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site.ru.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin support@site.ru
    ServerName site.ru
    ServerAlias www.site.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site.ru/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/site.ru.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/site.ru.private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/site.ru.intermediate.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Перезагружаю *apache*, захожу по *https* адресу, сайт недоступен

Что делаю не так?

Comment: вероятно, *apache* не смог загрузиться. смотрите в логе, почему не смог: `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log`

Comment: [ssl:emerg] [pid 14352] AH02565: Certificate and private key site.ru:443:0 from /etc/ssl/site.ru.crt and /etc/ssl/site.ru.private.key do not match

Comment: перевожу: сертификат подписан другим ключом. не тем, что лежит в `/etc/ssl/site.ru.private.key`.

Comment: Написал в тех поддержку reg.ru, оказалось выдали неправильные данные)

Comment: если проблема решится заменой сертификата (или ключа) — удалите, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос: на это есть право только у вас и у модераторов.