# Установка Сертификата на VPS

Tags: ssl, https, apache2

Доброго

Перенес свой сайт, на другой VPS, ест-но на нем, хочу к нему прибить сертификат.

```
//0. ест-но сайт у меня не mysite.com, просто я не хочу палит сайт ))

//1. положил файлы сертификата на хост
/etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.com/chain.crt        //SSLCACertificateFile
/etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.com/sertificat.crt   //SSLCertificateFile
/etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.com/sertificat.key   //SSLCertificateKeyFile

//2. задаю конфиг Apache2

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias *.mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/htdocs

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-access.log combined

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.com/sertificat.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.com/sertificat.key
SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.com/chain.crt 

ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/mysite.com/htdocs
</VirtualHost>

//4. перезагружаю апач
```

при заходе на сайт - ест-но ни страницы, ни чего, от хостинг компании красивая картинка об ошибке. и самое страшное логи пусты. т.е. в mysite-error.log и mysite-access.log нет

возникает вопрос, что делать? как диагностировать? Прошу совета, посвятите, что сделал не так. Может htaccess как то поправить? Может Apache?

p.s. ест-но умею пользоваться поиском, [эта тема НЕ аналогична моей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/436384/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-ssl-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-vps)

```
//в ответе SSH вот такое
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.


//upd - Degrag comment

[Thu Apr 12 03:48:03.579709 2018] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 9754:tid 139953337550720] AH00292: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 12 03:48:03.579729 2018] [core:notice] [pid 9754:tid 139953337550720] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Apr 12 05:21:11.135532 2018] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 9754:tid 139953337550720] AH00295: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Apr 12 05:21:12.420843 2018] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 24753:tid 140389450921856] AH00292: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 12 05:21:12.420946 2018] [core:notice] [pid 24753:tid 140389450921856] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Apr 12 05:26:45.061630 2018] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 24753:tid 140389450921856] AH00295: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Apr 12 05:27:46.315311 2018] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 24888:tid 140332804118400] AH00292: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 12 05:27:46.315443 2018] [core:notice] [pid 24888:tid 140332804118400] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Apr 12 05:29:10.656583 2018] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 24888:tid 140332804118400] AH00295: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Apr 12 05:29:32.218888 2018] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 24985:tid 140572168161152] AH00292: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 12 05:29:32.218994 2018] [core:notice] [pid 24985:tid 140572168161152] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Apr 12 06:21:46.858341 2018] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 24985:tid 140572168161152] AH00295: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Apr 12 06:22:11.614729 2018] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 25390:tid 140047255259008] AH00292: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 12 06:22:11.614861 2018] [core:notice] [pid 25390:tid 140047255259008] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

    root@ovz1:~# journalctl -xe
Apr 12 06:21:46 ovz1 apache2[25357]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Apr 12 06:21:47 ovz1 apache2[25357]:  *
Apr 12 06:21:47 ovz1 apache2[25357]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Apr 12 06:21:47 ovz1 apache2[25357]: Output of config test was:
Apr 12 06:21:47 ovz1 apache2[25357]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 8 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/technical.conf:
Apr 12 06:21:47 ovz1 apache2[25357]: Invalid command 'SSLEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server co
Apr 12 06:21:47 ovz1 apache2[25357]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Apr 12 06:21:47 ovz1 apache2[25357]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Apr 12 06:21:47 ovz1 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 12 06:21:47 ovz1 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
-- The result is failed.
Apr 12 06:21:47 ovz1 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 12 06:21:47 ovz1 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 12 06:22:11 ovz1 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Unit apache2.service has finished shutting down.
Apr 12 06:22:11 ovz1 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
Apr 12 06:22:11 ovz1 apache2[25375]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Apr 12 06:22:12 ovz1 apache2[25375]:  *
Apr 12 06:22:12 ovz1 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

-- Unit apache2.service has finished starting up.
-- The start-up result is done.
Apr 12 06:22:25 ovz1 sshd[25316]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
Apr 12 06:28:14 ovz1 sshd[25453]: Accepted password for root from 188.17.157.70 port 7418 ssh2
Apr 12 06:28:14 ovz1 sshd[25453]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 12 06:28:52 ovz1 sshd[25465]: Accepted password for root from 188.17.157.70 port 7472 ssh2
Apr 12 06:28:52 ovz1 sshd[25465]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 12 06:28:52 ovz1 sshd[25463]: Accepted password for root from 188.17.157.70 port 7471 ssh2
Apr 12 06:28:52 ovz1 sshd[25466]: Accepted password for root from 188.17.157.70 port 7473 ssh2
Apr 12 06:28:52 ovz1 sshd[25466]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 12 06:28:52 ovz1 sshd[25463]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 12 06:28:52 ovz1 sshd[25467]: Accepted password for root from 188.17.157.70 port 7474 ssh2
Apr 12 06:28:52 ovz1 sshd[25467]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 12 06:29:53 ovz1 sshd[25463]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
Apr 12 06:29:53 ovz1 sshd[25467]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
Apr 12 06:29:53 ovz1 sshd[25466]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
Apr 12 06:29:54 ovz1 sshd[25465]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
lines 1208-1263/1263 (END)
```

Comment: ну так а что в основном `error.log` Апача написано? либо `journalctl -xe` что говорит?

Comment: обновил. лог и команду. чесн. сказать, чувствую себя Алисой в стране линукса )

Comment: `Invalid command 'SSLEngine'` - mod_ssl не подключен. Выполните `a2enmod ssl`

Comment: оно, жаль справки по SSL пишут не такие как Вы! ошибки нет. правда при заходе на https бросает на http

Comment: разобрался, после чудесной команды, можно идти по мануалу - http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/apache_%D0%B8_https. Defrag, еще раз спс.